# Electron browser application - Memory leak

Tags: jquery, electron, chromium

I developed an electron browser application that needs to reload SVG content every 10 seconds. At startup application occupies 120MB, after 14 hours of operation takes up 3GB. The code with which I load the SVG element is as follows

```
var url = controllerUri + "/svgcontent";
postData = { ... };
$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: postData,
   success: function (data) {
      if (data != "") {
         $("#svgdiv").empty().off("*");
         $("#svgdiv").append(data);
      } else {
         $("#svgdiv").append("<div class='col-md-12 text-center mt-5'><h1>no data message</h1></div>");
      }
   },
   error: function () { ... }
});
```

SVG size is 125 KB

Do you have any suggestions to try understand what the memory leak might depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read in several other posts that chromium may have problems with image garbage. That's why I changed my implementation. With data refresh, I now retrieve the information to be applied to SVG elements. After 5 hours of observation, the electron process behaves correctly with the occupation and release of memory